SQL Server 2012 trying to update fill missing bill no sequence continously and count?
I have this data in a SQL Server 2012 table:



bill_no
datetime




3125
2022-12-26 14:17:21.000


3125
2022-12-26 14:17:21.000


3126
2022-12-26 14:31:48.000


3126
2022-12-26 14:31:48.000


3127
2022-12-26 14:39:31.000


3128
2022-12-26 14:44:06.000


3129
2022-12-26 14:46:02.000


3130
2022-12-26 14:53:35.000


3130
2022-12-26 14:53:35.000


3276
2022-12-26 15:19:22.000


3285
2022-12-26 16:52:09.000


3285
2022-12-26 16:52:09.000


3285
2022-12-26 16:52:09.000


3286
2022-12-26 17:33:28.000


3286
2022-12-26 17:33:28.000


3286
2022-12-26 17:33:28.000


3286
2022-12-26 17:33:28.000


3286
2022-12-26 17:33:28.000


3287
2022-12-26 17:39:06.000


3288
2022-12-26 17:41:46.000


3289
2022-12-26 17:55:42.000


3290
2022-12-26 18:11:45.000


3291
2022-12-26 18:21:27.000



And my desired result would look like this:



bill_no
datetime




3125
2022-12-26 14:17:21.000


3125
2022-12-26 14:17:21.000


3126
2022-12-26 14:31:48.000


3126
2022-12-26 14:31:48.000


3127
2022-12-26 14:39:31.000


3128
2022-12-26 14:44:06.000


3129
2022-12-26 14:46:02.000


3130
2022-12-26 14:53:35.000


3130
2022-12-26 14:53:35.000


3131
2022-12-26 15:19:22.000


3132
2022-12-26 16:52:09.000


3132
2022-12-26 16:52:09.000


3132
2022-12-26 16:52:09.000


3133
2022-12-26 17:33:28.000


3133
2022-12-26 17:33:28.000


3133
2022-12-26 17:33:28.000


3133
2022-12-26 17:33:28.000


3133
2022-12-26 17:33:28.000


3134
2022-12-26 17:39:06.000



and so on ...

Do you have a question? This is just a completely unformatted data dump.

It does looks like you want to renumber bill_no without gaps:
with dataX as (
    select
        min(bill_no) over () as first_bill_no,
        dense_rank(bill_no) over (order by "datetime") - 1 as dr
    from T
)
select
    first_bill_no + dr as bill_no, 
    "datetime"
from dataX;

